# How to import MS ACCESS files to SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, import, oledb

I have an ACCESS file (name=guid) with a table called `dbo_Ps` with 5 columns.  I want to import it directly in SQL SERVER.

I tried this :

```
INSERT INTO testage SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source=C:\App_TempFiles\cbc622a8-695c-4867-a26c-de18618cf642;')...[dbo_Ps]
```

Previously I activated the `OPENROWSET` and `OPENDATASOURCE` support in SQL SERVER.  I also installed MS Office 2010 Pro 64 bits.

Finally I got this error message:

```
Msg*7399, Niveau*16, État*1, Ligne*1
Le fournisseur OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" du serveur lié "(null)" a rapporté une erreur. Accès refusé.
Msg*7301, Niveau*16, État*2, Ligne*1
Impossible d'obtenir l'interface requise ("IID_IDBCreateCommand") à partir du fournisseur OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" du serveur lié "(null)".

Le fournisseur OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" du serveur lié "(null)" a rapporté une erreur. Accès refusé.
Msg*7301, Niveau*16, État*2, Ligne*1
Impossible d'obtenir l'interface requise ("IID_IDBCreateCommand") à partir du fournisseur OLE DB "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" du serveur lié "(null)".
```

What did I forget?

Comment: Accès refusé --> Check your connection has the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: SQL Server Import and Export Wizard]